# Solution for updating a record when you require a particular field Unique

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I have a table

```
ProjectID
ProjectName
Project description
```

Project Name is required to be unique. To implement the unique logic, i am sending the name of the project name to Stored Procedure as

```
Create proc CheckName
@Project Name
as
begin
select count(ProjectName)
where ProjectName=@Project Name
```

it return count to CS page and i check that as 
  if(count>0)
  {
     //Add
  }

This code works fine with addition. Now when i want to update the project description field, the check for Project Name again goes and it return Count 1 (which is obvious) and display Project Name already exist and i am not able to update other field of the table.

What other Logic can be implemented to maintain the unique field in the table. Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not add a **unique constraint** on the **ProjectName** column? Make the **ProjectID as primary key**, and **put an identity seed on it**, so that it auto increments. This will also automatically add clustered index to ProjectID column. Also, **set the collation of your database to LATIN1_GENERAL_CI_AI**, so that the ProjectName column values are compared in a case-insensitive way by the database. If you need case-sensitive comparison, you can set the collation to LATIN1_GENERAL_CI_AS. To add a unique key constraint to the ProjectName column, just do:

```
ALTER TABLE PROJECT ADD CONSTRAINT
            UX_PROJECT_NAME UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
    (
                PROJECTNAME
    )
```

Now all you need to do after that is update or insert, and if a duplicate project name is inserted/updated, an exception will be thrown, which you can catch and process.

Comment: Thanks sir, Unique Constraint just have skipped from my mind. You have save me from lot of coding in Business logic code.

Answer (score 0):

An example to implement update of a records, when You want a particular field to be unique

```
 string connectionstring = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[""].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertEmployee", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
            cmd.Parameters["@Id"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmpName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
            cmd.Parameters["@EmpName"].Value = Convert.ToString(TextBox2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Salary", SqlDbType.Decimal);
            cmd.Parameters["@Salary"].Value = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox3.Text);
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex )
            {
                if (ex.Message.Contains("UNIQUE KEY constraint"))
                Lblmessage.Text = "Field already exist";
            }
```